# svg rect image is not displayed on firefox

Tags: css, image, firefox, svg, d3.js

1. Currently, I'm working with D3 , but whne I try to put a image svg into a rect that is not displayed on firefox. That's the code generated:

   ```
     <g transform=translate(3,2)">
     <svg viewBox="0 0 300 200">
     <rect class="background" x="0" width="58" height="80" style="fill: #80a2cb"></rect>
     <image class="img"  href="https://trac.openstreetmap.org/export/6357/subversion/applications/share/map-icons/svg/vehicle/motorbike.svg" x="0" width="58" height="80"></image>
     </svg>
      </g>
   ```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

That image "href" needs to be an "xlink:href".

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes to transform attribute:

```
<g transform="translate(3,2)">
```